# wordpress styles in the head - don't want

Tags: css, wordpress, head

I am using thematic and have created a childtheme.

Whilst trying to style something in the header I discovered that in my head there are some inline stlyes.

How do I get rid of these styles please:

```
<style type="text/css">
                #blog-title, #blog-title a, #blog-description {
            color:#blank;
        }
                #branding {
            background-position: center bottom;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            margin-top: 32px;
        }
        #blog-title, #blog-title a, #blog-description {
            display:none;
        }
        #branding { 
            height:235px; 
            width:940px;
            padding:0; 
        }
            </style>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks all.

I have found the offending code. Its burried in the functions.php file in the sample theme that comes with thematic.

Seems a bit weird to me that its in there really... still, it isn't now!

Answer (score 1):

These styles are likely being added by a function hooked to the `wp_head` action. For example, something in either your theme or maybe in a plugin you have activated is doing something like this:

```
function hook_css() {
    $output = '<style> .example { color : #eee; } </style>';
    echo $output;
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hook_css', 10 );
```

You can either delete the function and the hook to `wp_head` or you can remove the action via the `remove_action()` function. For example:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'hook_css', 10 );
```

Ref:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a url for us to look at?

A quick way would be to use jQuery to strip it out.

```
$('head style').remove();
```

However removing it properly via php or the theme/plugin would be best

Answer (score 0):

These are generated by theme settings in the admin area, your best option is to find the hook to wp_head and just remove it if it's that necessary.